# webpage not showing from the Top of the page

Tags: php, html, css

Please have look at this page & its source code.
http://www.chemfluence.org.in/monetarist/index_copy.php

Web page is not showing from top of the web page. There is a gap of around 10px from top of the browser.
[image]

I have higlighted the gap in above image. 
Could you please anyone tell me how to display the page from top 0px ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome has a default margin of 8px built into the browser, in your CSS use:

```
body{ margin: 0 }
```

It's always handy to use some sort of CSS reset, to prevent inconsistencies like the above between browsers.

Something like this: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Still there is a gap of 2px
Please see, http://www.chemfluence.org.in/monetarist/index_copy.php
I need the page like http://www.chemfluence.org

Answer (score 1):

This is because you haven't explicitly set a `margin` for the `body` of your document and some browsers then use a default one.

To fix that, add something like this to your CSS stylesheet:

```
body {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Still there is a gap of 2px
Please see, http://www.chemfluence.org.in/monetarist/index_copy.php
I need the page like http://www.chemfluence.org

Comment: Change your table to: <table width="1350" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

Answer (score 1):

The default browser style sheets add a margin to the body Tag, so you have to set the margin of the body to 0:

```
html,body {margin:0;}
```

By the way, you should not use a table as a layout grid.

Comment: Still there is a gap of 2px
Please see, http://www.chemfluence.org.in/monetarist/index_copy.php
I need the page like http://www.chemfluence.org